# Как выбрать прямую ссылку из гугловского url с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо из ссылок вида

```
https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://tower43.ru/b0013232&ct=ga&cd=CAEYACoTMzUwODg1NjAwNzEwMDkwNjAyMjIcM2Q5YzNlZTJkOGNlNDNhNTpydTplbjpSVTpSTA&usg=AFQjCNH-ApyoRaD_cwKMe5tj6JwiB6Qpcg
```

Получать ссылки вида:

```
tower43.ru/b0013232
```

С помощью [сервиса](https://regex101.com/r/vO6kO3/1) написал регулярку, которая не работает в java-коде (возвращает false)

```
 String pattern = Pattern.quote("/(\\S)(https?:[\\S]*)(&ct=ga&cd=)/");
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
 Matcher m = p.matcher(url);

 boolean pure_url = m.find();
 System.out.println(pure_url);
```

Причем на сайте пишет, что есть совпадения.

Comment: `m.find()` возвращает `true` / `false`. Вам нужно использовать `.group(1)` - `if (m.find()) {  System.out.println(m.group(1)); }`

Comment: регулярки не нужны. Используйте встроенные средства для парсинга урла и вытягивайте параметр url с Query - [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так,

```
    String str = ...;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.+?url=(http[s]?://[\\w.]+.*?)&");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```